# Something is not right with my .click() function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to this forum so I will try to be as specific as possible without breaking the rules of the community. I'm trying to develop a gallery which uses the Flippy jQuery plugin. I have already installed the plugin which works great. What I want to achieve now is to find a way to assign a button that triggers the event to a specific div without seeing it repeated to all the other divs of the body.

In this link [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1481984/flippy%20test/index.html) you can see how each green button is supposed to call the Flippy event for each of the blue boxes. The problem is that when I click any green box the Flippy plugin is called and all the blue boxes get affected at once, which is definitely not what I want. How do I make it so that the green box number one calls the blue box number one and so on...? Now I understand this has something to do with the javascript but I cannot really see where the problem is. I hope you guys can help me with that!

Thank you very much!

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".boxlink").click(function(){ 
            $(".box").flippy({
                color_target: "red",
                direction: "RIGHT",
                duration: "500",
                noCSS: "true"
            });
        });
    });

    $(".box").flippyReverse();
</script>

<div class="flipboxcontainer">
    <div class="boxcontainer">
        <div class="box" id="1"></div>
        <div class="box" id="2"></div>
        <div class="box" id="3"></div>
        <div class="box" id="4"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="actionbuttons-btn">
    <div class="boxlink"></div>
    <div class="boxlink"></div>
    <div class="boxlink"></div>
    <div class="boxlink"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Get the index of the clicked `boxlink` and then initialize flippy to the box in that index

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $boxes = $(".box");
    var $links = $(".boxlink").click(function () {
        var index = $links.index(this);
        $boxes.eq(index).flippy({
            color_target: "red",
            direction: "RIGHT",
            duration: "500",
            noCSS: "true"
        });
    });
});
//you may have to move this to dom ready handler
$(".box").flippyReverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's ok to use just numeric values in id attributes, I wouldn't recommend it.
To make sure you link to the right boxes use id's on all elements:

```
 <div class="flipboxcontainer">
     <div class="boxcontainer">
        <div class="box" id="box_1"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box_2"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box_3"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box_4"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="actionbuttons-btn">
    <div class="boxlink" id="link_1"></div>
    <div class="boxlink" id="link_2"></div>
    <div class="boxlink" id="link_3"></div>
    <div class="boxlink" id="link_4"></div>
 </div>
```

And in the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".boxlink").click(function(){ 
        var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);
        $('#box_'+id).flippy({
            color_target: "red",
            direction: "RIGHT",
            duration: "500",
            noCSS: "true"
        });
    });
});

$(".box").flippyReverse();
```

Answer (score -1):

In your **flippyReverse** function, define the same css as that of **flippy**. 
Just change the color to "blue"